# Cutting butcher block countertops after I seal them?

Tags: wood, countertops

I'm installing butcher block countertops in my kitchen. I'm just wondering what, if any, issues I'll have by cutting them after I seal them rather than before? Obviously would seal the cut ends but I can't have our kitchen down for a couple weeks while I seal so to do it prior would be helpful

Comment: If you seal before and then cut, you have unsealed raw wood at the cut/s, that need sealing again.  With good measurements that are double checked, then sealing after the cuts should not be a problem.

Comment: Are these pre-made countertops, or made by you?  What product was used to seal them?  If it's an oil, or hard wax oil, your kitchen shouldn't be out of service while you seal the cut.  If you're using a heavy, solvent-based polyurethane with lots of VOCs, you won't want anyone to be around while the product is being applied and curing.

Comment: I mean, I guess if it's a cut end that's being sealed it should be fine because your sealant can dry (or cure) if you're careful not to bump up against the edges.